# VB.Net INSERT using a transaction & re-use the Last INSERTED ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to use a `SqlTransaction` in VB.Net to perform an insert to two tables, I want to insert the last inserted ID from the first table in a column at the second table.

I want to use the `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` instead of the `@SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Here is the two query extracted from SQL Server Profiler:

```
INSERT INTO USER(USER_NAME) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.USER_ID 
VALUES (@USER_NAME)

INSERT INTO USER_ADDRESS(USER_ID, USER_ADDRESS) 
VALUES ('', GETDATE(), ''001'', @OPD_OVP_NO, @OPD_PAT_CODE, @OPD_DATE, @OPD_AMOUNT)
```

Here is the VB.Net code:

```
    Dim sqlTransaction As SqlTransaction= sqlConnection.BeginTransaction
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = sqlConnection}
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USER(USER_NAME) OUTPUT INSERTED.USER_ID VALUES (@USER_NAME)"
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_NAME", "ABC")
    sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear()
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USER_ADDRESS(USER_ID,USER_ADDRESS)VALUES(@LASTID, @USER_ADDRESS)"
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTID", LASTID)'//LAST ID should be from the previously inserted ID
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ADDRESS","AB Street")
    sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    sqlTransaction.Commit()
```

I checked other threads but they only show how to get the last inserted ID from `@SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or from the `OUTPUT INSERTED.USER_ID`, but nothing on how to re-use that value for another insert statement.

Comment: In this case, since you're using a user-input as Id, the best practice might be to include a datetime column as InputDate, which can be used for re-use. Else, you will need to select the inserted value such as `select User_id from .. where user_name = 'ABC'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - INSERT with Scope_Identity() - getting the record id](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16083181/11683)

Comment: @GSerg the answer on the thread you suggests to use a single ExecuteNonQuery() but I want each query to run separately in a transaction.

Comment: @GSerg The reason is because I'm building the query dynamically & I don't want the @@params to be mixed up.

Comment: Then you should read up on [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) vs [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use the INSERTED.ID of the first insert statement into the second statement.

You should store it in a temporary table first using OUTPUT INTO.

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(USER_ID int);
DECLARE @NewUserID int;

INSERT INTO USER(USER_NAME)
OUTPUT INSERTED.USER_ID INTO @MyTableVar
VALUES (@USER_NAME);

SET @NewUserID = (SELECT USER_ID FROM @MyTableVar);

INSERT INTO USER_ADDRESS(USER_ID, USER_ADDRESS)
VALUES(@NewUserID, @USER_ADDRESS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a single, compound statement that performs both inserts:

```
create table [User] (User_ID int identity(97,-1) not null,
                     User_Name varchar(19) not null)
create table User_Address (User_ID int not null,
                           User_Address varchar(22) not null)

declare @User_Name varchar(19)
declare @User_Address varchar(22)

select @User_Name = 'abc', @User_Address='def'

insert into User_Address (User_ID,User_Address)
select User_ID,@User_Address
from (
        insert into [User] (User_Name)
        output inserted.User_ID
        select @User_Name
    ) t

select * from [User]
select * from User_Address
```

Result:

```
User_ID     User_Name
----------- -------------------
97          abc

User_ID     User_Address
----------- ----------------------
97          def
```

Comment: Why the nested `select`? `insert into User(User_Name) output inserted.User_ID, @User_Address into UserAddress(User_ID,User_Address) values(@User_Name)`

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to this sort of thing is to perform the transaction in a SQL Stored Procedure rather than using a client-controlled transaction.   The stored procedure will be able to access use the ID from the first insert and use it in the second insert without complicating things with an output parameter back to the client.   Furthermore, your DB will scale much better because it will keep the transaction duration as short as possible..