# Custom SQL Select statement not displaying data in GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

```
SELECT 
    LeagueTable.P,
    LeagueTable.W,
    LeagueTable.D,
    LeagueTable.L,
    LeagueTable.GF,
    LeagueTable.GA,
    LeagueTable.GD,
    LeagueTable.Pts,
    Team.Team_name,
    LeagueTable.Team_ID
FROM LeagueTable
INNER JOIN Team 
    ON LeagueTable.Team_ID = Team.Team_ID
```

[image]

I've got the user to enter a team name on start up that is entered into the `Team` table, which redirects to a webpage with a league table. The league table initially contains no data but it should be displaying a row with the users input once the user has gotten to this page.

However this query shows the GridView as blank. What's wrong with it?

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="No teams entered into the table.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="P" HeaderText="P" SortExpression="P" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="W" HeaderText="W" SortExpression="W" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="D" HeaderText="D" SortExpression="D" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="L" HeaderText="L" SortExpression="L" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GF" HeaderText="GF" SortExpression="GF" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GA" HeaderText="GA" SortExpression="GA" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GD" HeaderText="GD" SortExpression="GD" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pts" HeaderText="Pts" SortExpression="Pts" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Team_name" HeaderText="Team_name" SortExpression="Team_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Team_ID" HeaderText="Team_ID" SortExpression="Team_ID" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

            protected void NewTeamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    string qry1 = "INSERT into Team (Team_name) VALUES (@Team_name)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(("@Team_name"), SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewTeamTxtBox.Text;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    Response.Redirect("EnterData.aspx");
}
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SportsData2ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT LeagueTable.League_ID, LeagueTable.Team_ID, LeagueTable.P, LeagueTable.W, LeagueTable.D, LeagueTable.L, LeagueTable.GF, LeagueTable.GA, LeagueTable.GD, LeagueTable.Pts, Team.Team_name FROM LeagueTable INNER JOIN Team ON LeagueTable.Team_ID = Team.Team_ID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How are you calling the query? And how are you putting the result in the gridview?

Comment: Can you show us the data binding code?

Comment: I have it set to a custom SQL select query inside an SQL data source. I've attached my GridView to the original question.

Comment: From what you say the user enters a team name, which is then added to the team table and then redirected to the league page.  If you notice you have an Inner Join on your select.  If the team is new, then I find it hard to believe there are any rows already existing in the league table.  Just from grammar I'm confused about 1 team having many leagues.  Anyway, have you tried running your SQL against the database directly to affirm you should have any data showing?

Comment: The user has to create the league table of all the teams in there themselves. I don't mean to have one team having many leagues, I'm not sure about my database relations. Yes and it returned nothing even when I have a list of teams in the `Team` table

Comment: What I'm really asking is when I make a record for the `Team` table how do I make it so that a record is made in `LeagueTable` with the same `Team_ID`?

Comment: That question is not really related to what you posted.  you should clean up your question then or ask a new one.

Comment: Would you know why no data is being populated from this select query? Anything I try gives nothing back

Comment: I'm still not sure if this is a data issue or an implementation issue.  Can you affirm that the query you have on your sql data source does in fact return rows?  If so then you are probably not calling DataBind or something in your code behind.  you should post that code.

Comment: This select statement returns no rows whatsoever because there is no row created inside `LeagueTable` like I want it to. I have attached above the insert method I am using.

Comment: Your insert statement does not add a row to LeagueTable, only to Team.  You have to write another insert to add it to LeagueTable...

Comment: I have tried this solution but my insert methods would not work. I want to share the same Team_ID between tables so how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it appears you may be inserting data into your Team table, but when you run the select statement you have in your SQL Data Source you will notice you have an `Inner Join`.  That `Inner Join` means that if the team Id is not in either one of the 2 tables you are joining then no results will be returned.

I don't see your sql data source code, but another possible point of failure is the TeamID you pass into that control.  There are 3 questions that come to my mind for making sure you get valid data.

1)  Where are you getting it from?

2)  Is it valid and in both tables?

3)  Are you rebinding the gridview after setting that value?

**Edit**

What you want to do does not at all match your question at this point.  You should edit your title and question.

I would use something like this for your insert.

```
DECLARE @TeamID as INT
INSERT into Team (Team_name) VALUES (@Team_name)

SELECT @TeamID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT into LeagueTable Team_ID VALUES @TeamID
```

this post will help [Scope_Identity vs @@Identity](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083181/sql-insert-with-scope-identity-getting-the-record-id) stack question will help too.

Comment: I've added the SQL data source for you. `Team_ID` is in both tables and I can't apply `GridView1.DataBind();` since this button leads to another page.

Comment: It works! Needed to change the syntax for the last line to `INSERT into (LeagueTable) Team_ID VALUES (@TeamID)` and then change `League_ID` to IsIdentity = on. However, I now get each row having a different `League_ID`. Does this matter for later queries that use this table? I don't want teams to be separated by different leagues, I am just using it as a primary key.

Comment: You have a 1 to many relationship between the tables - however your comment sounds like there is no reason to have the 2 tables separated.  Why do you have a separate table for just the team name?  You may want to combine them into a single table.

Comment: It was suggested by others in another question that my database structure should have this layout. I have other tables that rely on gathering a `Team_name` such as a table `Match Statistics` that gathers `Home_Team_ID` and `Away_Team_ID` that gets the team names from that list.